# How can retrive address using Google map API3 from mysql data base

Tags: php, dictionary, store

Hello awesome programmers, Please help me.. I have been trying to create a dynamic maps following google's documentations but I am getting errors even if copy paste their codes.. here is the link of that documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#outputting-xml-with-php

I want the user input their address and like to store their address in lat and lang format .. when a user will search for the address , the script will search the data base and show the address that is human readable..

If anyone of you know any good source from where I can learn or buy or can give me tips I will be really happy... I have been looking for the solutions but still no solutions :(

Comment: I don't know anything about Google maps, but I do know Google. They don't give away data for free, they are not in the market to help you. The developer services are there so you can help them. Translating addresses to coordinates is a service you would normally have to pay for, if Google offers it at all.

Comment: They have free and paid version.. And member like me can have have the free service and we cannot even finish the free quote